# Integral curve on complete surfaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves

I proved the following result

"Prove that if $V$ is a differentiable vector field on a **compact surface** $S$ and $\alpha(t)$ is the maximal trajectory of $V$ with $\alpha(0)=p\in S$, then $\alpha(t)$ is defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}.$"

> For every $q\in S$, there exist a neighborhood $B$ of $q$ and an interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ such that the trayectory $\alpha(t)$, with $\alpha(0)=q$, is defined in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. By compactness, it's possible to cover $S$ with a finite numbers of such neighborhoods, ${B_j}'s$. Let $\varepsilon_0=\min\{\varepsilon_j\}$. If $\alpha(t)$ is defined for $t<t_0$ and isn't defined for $t_0$, we take $t_1\in (0,t_0)$, with $|t_0-t_1|<\varepsilon/3$. Consider the trayectory $\gamma(t)$ of $V$, with $\gamma(0)=\alpha(t_1)$, which leads us to a contradiction.

**My question**: Is the result valid if we have **complete surface** instead of **compact surface**? And if this is true (which I believe). How could it be demonstrated? I have tried but have not been successful.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with metric, so the completeness is not going to help you.

Comment: @ArcticChar metric? A regular surface $S$ is said be $complete$ when for every point $p\in S$ any parametrized geodesic $\alpha:[0,\varepsilon)\to S$ of $S$ starting from $p=\alpha(0)$ maybe extended into a parametrized geodesic $\overline{\alpha}:\mathbb{R}\to S$, defined on the entire line $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, so it is defined using a Riemannian metric $g$, and your question has nothing to do with $g$.

Comment: A simple counterexample: for $S = \mathbb{R}$, $V(x)=x^2$, $\alpha(0)=1$, one sees that $\alpha(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$ is not defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $S$ is a complete Riemannian manifold, and $V$ is a bounded vector field, then the previous reasoning holds.

Answer (score 2):

As Arctic Char pointed out, your quetion has nothing to do with any Riemannian structure. Here is an example of a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ which has a vector field with an integral curve that is not defined for all time.

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2,g)$ be the usual Euclidean plane. It is complete.

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{N\}$ be the standard diffeomorphism given by the sterographic projection from the north pole of the two sphere.

Let $X$ be any vector field on the $2$ sphere that is locally non-zero around the north pole $N$. Then there exists a non-constant integral curve of $X$ passing through $N$, say $\sigma$, at a time $t_0$.

Then $V = f^*X$ is a vector field of $(\mathbb{R}^2,g)$ and $f^*\sigma$ is an integral curve of $V$ which is not defined for $t = t_0$.

---

**Comment** Compactness is a topological property, while completeness is a metric property. Of course, every metric on a compact manifold is complete, but compactness results are not induced by metric statements: one couldn't expect your thought to be true because of that.

Comment: I understand my mistake, thank you very much. But my doubt arises when reading this paragraph from A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 3, 3rd Edition by Michael Spivak - page 252 - in the proof of Hilbert's theorem:

Comment: Select a point $p_0\in M$. Let $c:\mathbb{R}\to M$ be an asymptotic curve, parameterized by arclength, with $c(0)=p_0$; since $c$ is locally an integral curve of a unit vector field, it can be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ since $M$ is complete.

Comment: This may be a typo: this should be read "because $M$ is compact" I guess

Comment: It is not a typo because Hilbert's theorem says: A complete surface S with constant negative curvature cannot be isometrically immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Zaragosa That would be another question really. Please consider posting a new question and ask explicitly the proof by Spivak. The statement you stated is just wrong, if you include more information about the proof as a new question it is easier to see what is happening.